# What version of Android does Kindle 1st Gen run on?

Tags: android, kindle

I am using Amazon Maps SDK which requires API 13. I am wondering about the following

What version of android does the kindle first gen run on, are there updates for it since its released on version 10?

Will my app requiring min api level 13 be available for the first gen kindle fire on the market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Amazon's Device and Feature Specifications](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/kindle-fire/specifications/01-device-and-feature-specifications):

> Kindle Fire (1st Gen) is based on Android 2.3.3, API level 10

Per [Amazon Maps API FAQs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/maps/doc/faq):

> Q: On which Kindle Fire tablets is the Amazon Maps API supported?
>
> ```
> A: All Kindle Fire tablets and emulators except Kindle Fire (1st Generation).
> ```
>
> Q: Is Amazon Maps available on Kindle Fire (1st Generation)?
>
> ```
> A: No, Kindle Fire (1st Generation) does not include the maps library runtime.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://www.gsmarena.com/amazon_kindle_fire-4524.php kindle fire comes with gingerbread (api 9)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The correct answer is 2.3.3 API level 10.